# How can I keep some columns as is and dynamically pivot the last column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a table with 5 columns with values 0 or 1 and the last column `QuoteStatus` is of type `VARCHAR`.

I want to keep `ControlNo` and the other 4 columns as is, but the last column I need to pivot and also assign value either 0 or 1.

It can be more than 2 values: `Lost` or `No Action`.

So the data looks like this now:

[image]

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
                (
                    ControlNo INT, 
                    Bound INT, 
                    Declined INT, 
                    Rated INT, 
                    Quoted INT, 
                    QuoteStatus VARCHAR(50)
                )

INSERT INTO @Table1 (ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus)
VALUES
(1111,1,0,1,1,'Lost'),
(2222,0,1,0,1,'No Action'),
(3333,1,1,0,0,NULL),
(4444,1,0,0,1,'Lost'),
(5555,0,1,1,1,'No Action')
```

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We should use dynamic query to achieve the result.

In Dynamic Query :

1. Table variables are only visible in the scope where they are defined. They're like normal variables. Instead of table variable, I used temp tables.

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##A
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table1

Create table #Table1 
                (
                    ControlNo INT, 
                    Bound INT, 
                    Declined INT, 
                    Rated INT, 
                    Quoted INT, 
                    QuoteStatus VARCHAR(50)
                )

INSERT INTO #Table1 (ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus)
VALUES
(1111,1,0,1,1,'Lost'),
(2222,0,1,0,1,'No Action'),
(3333,1,1,0,0,NULL),
(4444,1,0,0,1,'Lost'),
(5555,0,1,1,1,'No Action')

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @finalquery  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QuoteStatus) 
            FROM #Table1 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @finalquery = '
select 
    p.controlno,p.Bound, p.Declined, p.Rated,p.Quoted,' + @columns + '
into ##A 
from 
    (
    select 
        ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus
from  #Table1
    )a
pivot 
    (
    max(QuoteStatus)
        for QuoteStatus IN (' + @columns + ')
    )p '

exec(@finalquery)

select 
    ControlNo,Bound, Declined, Rated,Quoted,
    case when Lost = 'LOST' then 1 else 0 end as Lost,
    case when [no action] = 'No Action' then 1 else 0 end as [No Action] 
from ##a

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) operator and for this problem I think you can get the result you want with something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table1 a
PIVOT ( COUNT(QuoteStatus) FOR QuoteStatus IN ( [Lost], [No Action] ) b
```